# Stop Google Forms from Rounding Up Decimals

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a simple form where I need exact inputs entered from form to sheet.  Unfortunately, Google forms is rounding up some of the data I enter.  Can this behavior be modified.

Example:

> Form Question: What is Price Per Share?
>   Response: $.0075
>   Number Submitted to Sheets: $.01

I understand why they might want to round up, but Price Per Share needs to be exact.  Any suggestions would be hugely helpful.

Just to add a little color.  It appears that Google Sheet is forcing the rounding, b/c it only saves two decimal points.  Is there a way to alter the number of decimal places that are saved?

Comment: What's the format for the column of data? If it's set to currency, it'll round to the hundredths. Try changing it to `Plain Text` to prevent rounding.

Comment: @BrianBennett, unfortunately even when I change the formatting it doesn't impact the input.  Additionally, when it does work, it strips the commas from the number.  I don't know what's going on.  Thank you for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a form validation (is number) and it will not round on the spreadsheet.  Full instructions here:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=en

You can also use a small script to format the number any way you like and set a trigger on form submit to run the script, here is a quick sample:

```
function numFormat(e) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  // select first sheet
 var col = "A" // change to the column that has the price per share
 var row = e.range.getRow();
 var cell = sheet.getRange(col+row);
 cell.setNumberFormat("$0.00000");  //set the format here
}
```

Different number formats can be found here under custom number formatting:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470